# Rails csrf protection fails sometimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf

I have a Rails 4 app with ajax calls and `jquery-rails` gem. And ***sometimes*** csrf protection fails for ajax calls.

I've never caught this problem myself, but some users have. One of them sent me screenshots and the source code of the page - there are no errors in JS console; csrf meta-tag presented on the page.

I really don't know what may causing this problem and how to debug it. Can you help me?

Comment: If you think you've encountered a bug in Rails go to their github page and file a report https://github.com/rails/rails/issues

Comment: Also get the user to specify which browser they are using, how they got to the page (make sure they haven't booked marked the form, and are loading a cached version)

Comment: @ReggieB, page not cached and not bookmarked. But user said, that he used incognito tab in Chrome, and i use default cokie store. May it cause a problem?
@Iceman, i don`t think that it is bug in rails - it's nothing specific in my app.

Comment: I'd be surprised if it was the cause of the problem, but I think you have to test the app yourself in a Chrome incognito tab to ensure it isn't a quirk of this environment.

Comment: Also have a look at the logs and see if authenticity_token is being passed in the params posted when this user submits the form. You may need to change the logging level at the server to see this.

Comment: @ReggieB, but token don't passed via params, it's posted as a X-CSRF-Token header. I forgot to say, that i use $.ajax to send form data, sorry. And i have `gem 'jquery-rails'` in my `Gemfile`, which sets this header.

Comment: `$.ajax` by itself won't add the right headers in. Can you show the code you use to do this?

Comment: @sevenseacat `jquery-rails` sets this header. https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js#L294

Answer (score 1):

A google query for [X-CSRF-Token header chrome incognito](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=X-CSRF-Token%20header%20chrome%20incognito) returns some interesting results.

In particular, have a look at ["I Saw An Extremely Subtle Bug Today And I Just Have To Tell Someone"](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2011/11/17/i-saw-an-extremely-subtle-bug-today-and-i-just-have-to-tell-someone/)

As @sevenseacat has pointed out, this is an old article regarding Rails 2 code, however the symptoms are very similar and I wonder if the underlying cause is the same - something is occasionally ending session which is invalidating the CSRF. Also, this problem may be an artifact of using Chrome in cognito mode.

In summary intermittent loss of session causes subtle CSRF bugs.

Comment: its interesting, but it's also a three year old article about Rails 2.3 - and the functionality has changed since then.

Comment: I know, but the symptoms seem too similar to be ignored. I don't think the exact cause will be the same. I'll update the 'Answer' to reflect what I think it most interesting about it.